# Higstock add all series dynamically

Tags: json, highcharts

I've a Higstock lineal graph. Sometimes I need to show just one serie, other times I need two or three series to draw.

Obviously, this is an example of adding series dynamically. I put:

```
$(function() { 
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({     
// ...
             series: []             
// ...
})
chart.addSeries({name : "Value1",data : value1Data});
chart.addSeries({name : "Value2",data : value2Data});
chart.addSeries({name : "Value3",data : value3Data});
```

But not working, the chart needs to have at least one serie with data values in "series" node, not allowing an empty series node, like I put before.

I need to add all my series dynamically.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8aP69/1/

FYI: The graph only draws the navigation bar.

Comment: Do you get data dynamically from database or somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but the data is present on that point, I can show it anywhere. The problem is just that I need to set series node with at least one of them, like jsfiddle example. Thanks Sebastian

Comment: You can get data from database, prepare json, get in javascript and load chart after loading json, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/X4zyr/

Comment: Thanks, but not working for me. If I've three series node, and one of them is empty, then this is not working. I probably need to use addSeries method. There must be something like series[{}] or series[{,}]. Thanks anyway

Comment: After getting json, when its empty serie, you can use slice() javascript function and after that, use in highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

After many little test, a man that I loved him give me the solution.

I need to set initial series node like that:

```
series: [{ name: "Serie1", data : [null]}]  // first serie has to be null
```

And after that, adding data point for first serie.

```
chart.series[0].setData(data1); // adding his data here
```